# ReactJS - Disable Bootstrap library dependency

Tags: reactjs

I have an app in `ReactJS` which is included inside the YII2 app. This YII2 app has some `CSS` styles. When I include the react app it comes with some `CSS` styles. I'm looking for a way to prevent using `_reboot.css` which is included as a dependency for `Bootstrap`.

Is there a way to tell react to not use this dependency of an imported library?

PS: Maybe I'm just doing it all wrong.
I have `<div id="app-container"></div>`
inside the YII2 app.

Thank you!

Comment: Afaik YII2 is a php framework. So how does your react app "import" it? If you mean that your backend serves this styles along with your react app you can't let react "ignore" them. The browser is responsible for applying css styles to the DOM nodes, not react.

Comment: I just import generated CSS and JS files on side of YII2 app. React app automatically hooks to #app-container. Maybe I didn't explain it correctly. I need to remove _reboot.css at side of reactjs app, so it doesn't influence YII2 app styles when I import it.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to explain. I want to remove _reboot.scss from bootstrap dependency in react application. So it's not served with react application. Forget about YII app. We talking only about react app here :)

Comment: are you looking for a reset.css? (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: No. I'm looking for a way to remove _reboot.css from my react app